# Does the set of operator monotone functions become larger if we restrict ourselves to real symmetric matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

$f$ is operator monotone if for all (Hermitian) matrices $X,Y\ge 0$ which  satisfy $X\ge Y$ we have $f(X)\ge f(Y)$.

There is a nice characterisation of the set of all operator monotone functions (defined on the positive half-line) given by $$f(t)=\int _0 ^1 \frac{t}{\lambda + (1-\lambda)t} d\mu (\lambda) $$ for a suitable measure $\mu$ ([Löwner’s theorem](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.0098.pdf)).

If we only require the functions $f$ to satisfy the aforesaid contraints for real symmetric matrices, does the resultant set remain the same or does it enlarge? (obviously since we have weakened our requirement the set can't shrink). In case of the latter, is there a known characterisation thereof?

PS: I must admit that I have not looked at the proof myself yet but I ask because it may be obvious to the experts.

Comment: It doesn't change, because every operator on a complex Hilbert space is still an operator when you consider the Hilbert space to be just real. In terms of matrices, this is equivalent to writing a complex hermitian matrix as a real symmetric matrix of twice the size [in the usual way](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2010172/represent-a-complex-valued-matrix-into-real-valued-matrix).

Comment: Wow. Thanks, you're right. $W_i$ would be anti-symmetric for a Hermitian matrix (as per the link) so the corresponding real matrix is symmetric. I feel so stupid. It had nothing to do with operator monotones :'D

Comment: @TobiasFritz: Maybe I'm missing something obvious here, but I don't understand two things: (1) If we consider a complex Hilbert space to be a real vector space, in which sense is it still a Hilbert space? More precisely, what is the inner product on it? (2) If we consider a matrix $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ as a matrix $\tilde A \in \mathbb{R}^{2n \times 2n}$ in the way linked by Tobias, why doesn't this affect (i) the spectrum of the matrix (and thus positivity) and (ii) the action of the functional calculus?

Comment: @JochenGlueck: (1) You can take the inner product to be given by the real part of the complex inner product. That still induces the same norm. (A neat fact is that the real part is a real inner product, while the imaginary part is a symplectic form!) (2) Doing that is exactly the same as forgetting the complex structure, just written down in a basis. So it's enough to show your (i) and (ii) for the 'forget the complex structure' construction. But there, functional calculus is trivially preserved, and therefore the spectrum as well.

Comment: @TobiasFritz: All right, now I got it. Thanks a lot for the explanation.